How to restore the version of a SharePoint list item using Power Automate?
How to restore a particular version history of a SharePoint list item using Power Automate
Please follow the below steps:

Create an MS flow
Get the version history of an item i.e. version label. If you want to restore the version of all the list items, then create an array and store item ids and version label into an array
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee%20Test')/items(id)/versions
Add a SharePoint HTTP action
Add site url
URI (when you are having a list at site collection level) _api/v2.0/sites/{siteID}/lists/{listID}/items/{itemID}/versions/{versionlabel}/restoreVersion

URI (when you are having list at subsite level)
_api/v2.0/sites/{siteID}/sites/{siteID}/lists/{listID}/items/{itemID}/versions/{versionlabel}/restoreVersion
How to get the site/web Id:
/_api/site/id

/_api/web/id

Note Remember to keep the version label in decimal format, like 1.0 or 10.0 etc.
img

Well, for me it's not works. Trayed these Uri (POST method):
_api/v2.0/sites/SITE ID/lists/LIST ID/items(ITEM ID)/versions(VERSION ID)/restoreVersion
_api/v2.0/sites(SITE ID)/lists(LIST ID)/items(ITEM ID)/versions(VERSION ID)/restoreVersion
where sting in CAPSLOCK are extracted dynamic variables


You need to build proper URI. I can see you didn't construct the URI properly, I have shown above. e.g. ..... items//versions//. The id and version label should not be in brackets.
